# Подключение и освобождение динамической библиотеки

Tags: c++

У меня подключается динамическая библиотека с несколькими функциями:

```
HINSTANCE load;
    load = LoadLibrary(L"DynamicLib.dll");
typedef int (*inputValue)();

    inputValue inputvalue;
    inputvalue = (inputValue)GetProcAddress(load, "inputValue");

    typedef int *(*inputArray)(int n);
    inputArray inputarray;
    inputarray = (inputArray)GetProcAddress(load, "inputArray");
```

и т.д.

Потом, в конце, я ее освобождаю:

```
FreeLibrary(load);
```

Так вот, если я подключаю библиотеку с несколькими функциями,
нужно ли создавать новую load и освобождать библиотеку для каждой, или хватит одной?

Comment: А зачем для каждой функции это делать?

Comment: Я сам не знаю, поэтому и спрашиваю

Comment: Хватит одной...